# Creating coded values with iteration from a field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, domains

I'd like to find a way to add coded values to a Text domain using values from a table field, if such a thing is even possible. I'm using the Add Coded Value to Domain tool connected to two variables: Name and Description. While this hasn't worked yet, what I've tried was making the value of each variable the same as the two field names from my table with the name and description I'd like to have. My syntax for Name was %VendorName% and my syntax for Description was %VendorDescription%. All this does is create a string literal %VendorName% coded value. Is what I'm trying to do possible?[image]

Comment: Can up upload a screen shot of your model?

Comment: Done! Sorry about that, I assumed my low rep wouldn't let me attach pics.

Comment: Also, I intentionally haven't included iteration--wanted to get one of the coded values to work first.

Answer (score 1):

I am just considering your attached image only.

Create a string variable (i see "Vendors" what you created) for "Code Value" and another for "Code description" (say you created "My Coded Value Description") as string. Then double click in the tools' "Code Value" and write %Vendors% ;again double click on  "Code Description" and write %My Coded Value Description% - care only % and inside the name. After all assign other two input "Workspace" and Domain". Now just run the model.

[image: demo]

In short
Name   "Vendors"------>    in model it will be exact with two leading and trailing % i.e.  %Vendors%

For naming valid character consult [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_attribute_domains).